# “Could not build wheels for pyunicorn” on MacOS using miniconda and pip – how to fix this problem?

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, miniconda

I would like to install pyunicorn ([https://www.pik-potsdam.de/~donges/pyunicorn/index.html](https://www.pik-potsdam.de/%7Edonges/pyunicorn/index.html)) on my intel Macbook with the current BigSur version 11.7.8. I use miniconda `conda 23.5.0` and pip `pip 23.1.2 from /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)`.

I installed the required dependencies for pyunicorn listed here: [https://www.pik-potsdam.de/~donges/pyunicorn/download.html](https://www.pik-potsdam.de/%7Edonges/pyunicorn/download.html) which worked out fine.

> Numpy 1.14+ Scipy 1.0+ igraph python-igraph 0.7+

However, once I try to install pyunicorn via `pip install pyunicorn`, I receive the following error:

```
Collecting pyunicorn
  Using cached pyunicorn-0.6.1.tar.gz (881 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14 in /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunicorn) (1.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyunicorn) (1.10.1)
Collecting python-igraph>=0.7 (from pyunicorn)
  Using cached python_igraph-0.10.5-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: igraph==0.10.5 in /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-igraph>=0.7->pyunicorn) (0.10.5)
Requirement already satisfied: texttable>=1.6.2 in /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from igraph==0.10.5->python-igraph>=0.7->pyunicorn) (1.6.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyunicorn
  Building wheel for pyunicorn (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [78 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn
      copying pyunicorn/conftest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn
      copying pyunicorn/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/interacting_networks.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/grid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/geo_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/resistive_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/netcdf_dictionary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      copying pyunicorn/core/data.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core/_ext
      copying pyunicorn/core/_ext/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/core/_ext
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/spearman.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/rainfall.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/hilbert.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/climate_data.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/tsonis.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/mutual_info.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/map_plots.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/coupled_climate_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/havlin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/climate_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/eventsynchronization_climatenetwork.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/partial_correlation.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      copying pyunicorn/climate/coupled_tsonis.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate/_ext
      copying pyunicorn/climate/_ext/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate/_ext
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/joint_recurrence_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/recurrence_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/cross_recurrence_plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/joint_recurrence_plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/visibility_graph.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/inter_system_recurrence_network.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/surrogates.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/recurrence_plot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries/_ext
      copying pyunicorn/timeseries/_ext/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/timeseries/_ext
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet
      copying pyunicorn/funcnet/event_synchronization.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet
      copying pyunicorn/funcnet/coupling_analysis_pure_python.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet
      copying pyunicorn/funcnet/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet
      copying pyunicorn/funcnet/coupling_analysis.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet/_ext
      copying pyunicorn/funcnet/_ext/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/funcnet/_ext
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/eventseries
      copying pyunicorn/eventseries/eca.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/eventseries
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils
      copying pyunicorn/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils
      copying pyunicorn/utils/navigator.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils
      copying pyunicorn/utils/mpi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils/progressbar
      copying pyunicorn/utils/progressbar/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils/progressbar
      copying pyunicorn/utils/progressbar/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils/progressbar
      copying pyunicorn/utils/progressbar/widgets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils/progressbar
      copying pyunicorn/utils/progressbar/progressbar.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/utils/progressbar
      running build_ext
      building 'pyunicorn.climate._ext.numerics' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate/_ext
      clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/include -I/Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Miniconda/miniconda3/include/python3.11 -c pyunicorn/climate/_ext/numerics.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-311/pyunicorn/climate/_ext/numerics.o -O3 -std=c99
      pyunicorn/climate/_ext/numerics.c:171:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
        #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyunicorn
  Running setup.py clean for pyunicorn
Failed to build pyunicorn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyunicorn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I was not able yet to solve this problem and wonder what options I have to further check for potential problems that cause this error?

Answer (score 2):

The latest version `pyunicorn` 0.6.1 was [released in 2019](https://pypi.org/project/pyunicorn/0.6.1/). It lists Python 3.7 as the only compatible version. A little while before that it was [migrated from Python 2.7 to 3.7](https://www.pik-potsdam.de/%7Edonges/pyunicorn/changelog.html).

I suspect it simply isn't compatible with Python 3.11. Try lower Python versions.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the fact that ```pyunicorn``` was not updated for a while.